# calling method from my asynctask must be static

Tags: android

I'm not sure why it is but I cannot call a method in my asynctask that is not static.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        List<SingleEvent> thelist = PhotosActivity.parseJSONResponse(result);


        PhotosActivity.refreshListView(thelist);




    }
```

The method in my activity:

```
public void refreshListView(List<SingleEvent> theList){//method that adds the List to the ListView after asyncTask is finished.

         SingleEventAdapter adapter = new SingleEventAdapter(this, theList);

         this.list.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

It says I should make my method static, but in doing so the code inside gets errors saying it cannot be used with static.

EDIT:

The following is my asynctask class:

```
public class CallWebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {}
```

it's not static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do this (make sure your `AsyncTask` class is not static):

```
PhotosActivity.this.refreshListView(thelist);
```

Comment: yes Im getting the error "no enclosing instance of PhotosActivity"

Comment: Is your asynctask class inside PhotosActivity? If no, then you must pass a reference to that activity to the constructor of your async task and keep a reference there.

Comment: How do you pass the reference?